# How do you display markdown value using jinja2?

Tags: python, html, markdown, jinja2

I process a string on the server using python markdown2 module.

```
marked_up = '    import sys\n    print "hello there"' 
marked_up = unicode(markdown2.markdown(marked_up, extras=["fenced-code-blocks"]))
```

Then, I pass the value through jinja2 to the client:

```
template_value = {'marked_up': marked_up}

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_value))
```

In the index.html I try to display this marked value:

```
<div class="row marketing" id="my_row_mark">

   {{ marked_up }}

</div>
```

The problem is that the text is shown with the html attributes:

```
<pre><code>import sys print "hello there" </code></pre>
```

I would like to see only:

```
import sys print "hello there"
```

with the proper markdown applied by markdown2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Use the [`|safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe) filter to prevent your content from getting automatically escaped:

```
{{ marked_up|safe }}
```

---

Jinja2 has a configuration option named [`autoescape`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Environment) that determines if content in templates should be automatically [HTML escaped](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#html-escaping) or not.

By default (if you're using plain Jinja2) autoescaping is disabled. But if your using a framework that integrates Jinja2, `autoescape` may very well be enabled.

So when autoescaping is enabled, any content you pass into a template will be HTML escaped. Note in this example how `content` will be escaped, which leads to you *seeing the HTML tags in the rendered HTML*:

**`example.py`**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'),
                  autoescape=True)              # <-- autoescaping enabled

template = env.get_template('index.html')
content = "<strong>bar</strong>"
print template.render(content=content)
```

**`index.html`**

```
<div>
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>
    &lt;strong&gt;bar&lt;/strong&gt;
</div>
```

---

You can now [prevent escaping for a particular variable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping) by using the [`|safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe) filter:

```
<div>
    {{ content|safe }}
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <strong>bar</strong>
</div>
```

For more details, see the documentation on [HTML escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#html-escaping).